# How to replace a d3js nest function with group and rollup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-structures

I'm struggling to translate some older d3js code to the newest version (V6). It seems the old function `nest()` has been deprecated. From now on the docs recommend using `group()` and `rollup()`, however, they don't give any real good examples and I struggle to achieve the same data structure with these new functions.

**Data Input:**

```
[
  {
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1990"
  },
  {
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1990"
  },
  {
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1971"
  },
  {
    name: "Markus",
    year: "1981"
  },
]
```

**Old D3 Code:**

```
let nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d.name })     
  .key(function (d) { return d.year })
  .rollup(function (leaves) { return leaves.length })
  .entries(data)
```

**Output (correct):**

```
[
  {
    key: "Anton"
    values: [
      {
        key: "1990",
        value: 2
      }
      {
        key: "1971",
        value: 1
      }
    ]  
  },
  {
    key: "Markus"
    values: [
      key: "1981"
      value: 1
    ]
  }
]
```

**New Code**

I tried to combine `group` and `rollup` in different ways, but I always end up with another data structure. The closes I've come is with this:

```
let rollup = d3.rollups(data, v => v.length, d => d.name, d => d.year);
let arrayFromRollup = Array.from(rollup, ([key, value]) => ({key, value}));
```

**Output (wrong)**

```
[
  {
    key: "Anton"
    values: [
      ["1990", 2],
      ["1971", 1]
    ]  
  },
  {
    key: "Markus"
    values: [
      ["1981", 1]
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm helpful for any advice, apparently, most similar questions/posts I've found are quite old and work with `nest`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

D3 provides excellent convenience functions, but with the rise of ES6, array and object manipulation has become a lot easier. You can achieve this using pure ES6 methods:

```js
const input = [{
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1990"
  },
  {
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1990"
  },
  {
    name: "Anton",
    year: "1971"
  },
  {
    name: "Markus",
    year: "1981"
  },
]

const expected = [
  {
    key: "Anton",
    values: [
      {
        key: "1990",
        value: 2
      },
      {
        key: "1971",
        value: 1
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "Markus",
    values: [
      {
        key: "1981",
        value: 1,
      }
    ],
  },
];

// For ease of use, start with an object, we map key to values
// and unpack it later. The structure we go for now:
// { name: { year: count }}
const nameYearsCount = input.reduce((obj, {
  name,
  year
}) => {
  if (!(name in obj)) {
    obj[name] = {
      [year]: 1
    };
  } else {

    // I.e. if the year doesn't exist, default to zero
    obj[name][year] = (obj[name][year] || 0) + 1
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

// Now transform it into the desired format
const result = Object.entries(nameYearsCount)
  .map(([name, yearsCount]) => {
    const values = Object.entries(yearsCount)
      .map(([year, count]) => ({
        key: year,
        value: count
      }));
    return {
      key: name,
      values
    };
  });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some good documentation on group and rollup:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group

Put the following in the observable as an example:

```
d3.rollup(athletes, 
      v => {return {values: {len: v.length, earn:d3.sum(v, d => d.earnings)}}; },
      d => {return {key: d.nation}},
      d => {return {key: d.sport}}
     )
```